# Transform n columns of events occurring together into two columns of pairs of occurrences

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, transpose

I currently have a table like this:

| A | B | C | D | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 50 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 100 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 200 |

where the first row indicates events A and B occurred together 50 times, second row indicates C occurred itself 100 times etc.

In reality I have around 10 events and as many combinations as 10 events allows and I want to transform the table into 3 columns, where the relevant rows for the above table would look like this

| Event1 | Event2 | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 50 |
| C | C | 100 |
| B | C | 200 |
| B | D | 200 |
| C | D | 200 |

I've no idea where to approach the issue from. I thought of looking at the SQL explode function, or pivoting the data but can't figure out how I'd do it for this data.

Comment: Is there a primary key, like an id, in the table?

Comment: @forpas the table is derived from a table with primary keys - the column headers (events) were all primary keys. There is no primary key in this table as it is just for counting / analysis purposes

Comment: Why are A->A, B->B and D->D omitted?

Comment: @berihulel as I mentioned in the post, I've only included the rows relevant to the table at the top. None of A, B or D occured in their own.

Comment: @15150776 . . . Why would you want C/C in the second example but not A/A in the first?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff because C occurred on its own and A didn't

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do this.  Here's one that can be expanded to handle many more columns by just adding `UNION` terms to the `data2` CTE term.  I'm sure there are ways to shorten this, but this is relatively clear.

I used MySQL 8.0.26 for this test case.

Note: MariaDB 10.5.0 has a few bugs in this area.  If you happen to try MariaDB, there may be a couple of edits necessary to work around those bugs.  Nothing horrible.  Just annoying.

- `data0` provides your initial table.
- `data1` just forces an order to that data and then assigns a unique id per row
- `data2` partially normalizes the data via `UNION`.  Add terms to handle more columns.
- `data`  adds a `COUNT` (`cnt`) within each `id` to identify an event which has no pair.
- `tcross` generates a partial cartesian product of pairs, preventing reflections, etc.

```
WITH data0 (a, b, c, d, n) AS (
         SELECT 1, 1, 0, 0,  50 UNION
         SELECT 0, 0, 1, 0, 100 UNION
         SELECT 0, 1, 1, 1, 200
     )
   , data1 (a, b, c, d, n, id) AS (
         SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) FROM data0 AS t
     )
   , data2 (event, n, id) AS (
         SELECT 'A', n, id FROM data1 WHERE a = 1 UNION
         SELECT 'B', n, id FROM data1 WHERE b = 1 UNION
         SELECT 'C', n, id FROM data1 WHERE c = 1 UNION
         SELECT 'D', n, id FROM data1 WHERE d = 1
     )
   , data (event, n, id, cnt) AS (
         SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) FROM data2 AS t
     )
   , tcross (event1, event2, n, id) AS (
         SELECT t1.event, COALESCE(t2.event, t1.event), t1.n, t1.id
           FROM      data AS t1
           LEFT JOIN data AS t2
             ON t1.id = t2.id
            AND t1.event < t2.event
          WHERE t2.event IS NOT NULL OR t1.cnt = 1
     )
SELECT event1, event2, n
  FROM tcross
 ORDER BY id, event1, event2
;
```

The result:

```
+--------+--------+-----+
| event1 | event2 | n   |
+--------+--------+-----+
| A      | B      |  50 |
| C      | C      | 100 |
| B      | C      | 200 |
| B      | D      | 200 |
| C      | D      | 200 |
+--------+--------+-----+
```

[Fully working test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e2fd4573d9e4240f482fd2cc398c05a7)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a brute force approach with `union all` like this:

```
select 'A' as event1, 'B' as event2, n
from t
where a = 1 and b = 1
union all
select 'A' as event1, 'C' as event2, n
from t
where a = 1 and c = 1
union all
select 'A' as event1, 'D' as event2, n
from t
where a = 1 and d = 1
union all
select 'B' as event1, 'C' as event2, n
from t
where b = 1 and c = 1
union all
select 'B' as event1, 'D' as event2, n
from t
where b = 1 and d = 1
union all
select 'C' as event1, 'D' as event2, n
from t
where c = 1 and d = 1;
```

You could also do a `join` approach:

```
select x.event1, x.event2, t.n
from t join
     (select 1 as a, 1 as b, 0 as c, 0 as d, 'A' as event1, 'B' as event2 union all
      select 1 as a, 0 as b, 1 as c, 0 as d, 'A' as event1, 'C' as event2 union all
      select 1 as a, 0 as b, 0 as c, 1 as d, 'A' as event1, 'D' as event2 union all
      select 0 as a, 1 as b, 1 as c, 0 as d, 'B' as event1, 'C' as event2 union all
      select 0 as a, 1 as b, 0 as c, 1 as d, 'B' as event1, 'D' as event2 union all
      select 0 as a, 0 as b, 1 as c, 1 as d, 'C' as event1, 'D' as event2
     ) x
     on (x.a = t.a or x.a = 0) and
        (x.b = t.b or x.b = 0) and
        (x.c = t.c or x.c = 0) and
        (x.d = t.d or x.d = 0);
```

Comment: This does not return the 2nd row of the expected results.